# How do I tell Typecript an interface will not have any undefined members

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like this

```
interface Person {
 name?:string;
age? :number;
gender?:string
}
```

I would like to use that exact same interface type somewhere else. But, I want to modify it telling that all members will never be undefined. So, it will be like this

```
 name:string;
age :number;
gender:string
```

Is there a way to modify an interface without rewriting an entire interface? Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that `null` and `undefined` are different things; optional properties can be `undefined` but not `null`; perhaps you want to change the word "null" to "undefined" in this question?

Comment: I've made this edit, by the way

Comment: Ok, thanks. Got the right answer from the guy below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the [Required<Type>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) utility type

> Constructs a type consisting of all properties of `Type` set to required. The opposite of [`Partial`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype).

```ts
type RequiredPerson = Required<Person>;
```

Note: Requires at least TypeScript v2.8

Comment: That works like a charm. But, do you also know how to make all the nested objects mandatory to provide?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJwLbTsg3gKGSOWABMB+ZALgGcwpQBzAbkOJEwkqrzeOJjAodAHKdytek1b9+NCAgD2IUmKzc6DEIz7IAvjOI1gkDVO349+a0pB1kg4WHRYoOKgCUIARwCuQiFIAHhdsAD5kAF4CfjJqAHIARniAGl0OLGpcPTS5ExQqeIALCAAbUsVkAHdFKFLSeMt8IA

Comment: @NyiNyiHmueAung you could use `DeepRequired<T>` from [this utility library](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types#deeprequiredt)